# Page not found error when clicked on the image url coming in the get api in Django

Tags: django, api, heroku, django-rest-framework, media

I have a simple get api built using **Django Rest Framework.** It is getting all the food items from the model, Menu. It consists of an image field. The api response is successful and I am getting an image URL in the image field, but when I click on that url, the image is not shown in the new tab. I have done a few projects and as far as I remember, it should show the image on the new tab. Due to this, the image is not shown in the frontend which is done in **Reactjs.** The backend in served in **Heroku** for now.

The url is similar as follows:

https://example.herokuapp.com/api/menus

The api response in local is as follows:

[image]

**And when I click  on the both image and image_url, it shows the follows:**

[image]

I added image_url just to see if it works, but it didnt work as well.

**My model:**

```
class Menus(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=CATEGORY,default='main courses')
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/pictures',null=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**My serializers:**

```
class MenusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')    

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        image_url = obj.image.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(image_url)



    class Meta:
        model = Menus
        fields = ['category','image', 'image_url','food_name',
                  'description','price','rating']
```

**My settings:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
django_heroku.settings(locals())

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/pictures')
```

**My project url:**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Note: Its not working on both locally and also on live api (on heroku).**

**Update:**

The folders look like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the directory of image manually. I guess it shouldn't be `media/media/pictures` but it should be `media/pictures`

Comment: ok what should my media_url be then? empty?? @ShivendraPratapKushwaha

Comment: no... please check manually where your image is uploaded. also check the `settings.DEBUG`.

Comment: my deub= true in settings.py....your below code is also not working.....

Comment: have you checked where your file is getting stored...??

Answer (score 0):

What changes you need to do is :

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
```

models.py

```
class Menus(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures',null=True)
    ...
```

Setting upload_to will check the location after MEDIA_ROOT.
Check the documentation here for the [storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage) of `FileField` or `ImageField`.

> Using a FileField or an ImageField (see below) in a model takes a few
> steps:
>
> 1.) In your settings file, you’ll need to define MEDIA_ROOT as the full
> path to a directory where you’d like Django to store uploaded files.
> (For performance, these files are not stored in the database.) Define
> MEDIA_URL as the base public URL of that directory. Make sure that
> this directory is writable by the Web server’s user account.
>
> 2.) Add the FileField or ImageField to your model, defining the upload_to option
> to specify a subdirectory of MEDIA_ROOT to use for uploaded files.
>
> 3.) All that will be stored in your database is a path to the file (relative
> to MEDIA_ROOT). You’ll most likely want to use the convenience url
> attribute provided by Django. For example, if your ImageField is
> called mug_shot, you can get the absolute path to your image in a
> template with {{ object.mug_shot.url }}.

Comment: Sorry @Shivendra, it didn't work...The files are inside the pictures folder inside media folder.

Comment: I have uploaded the folder picture above.

Comment: have you done the migrations as well after changing...?? and what are you getting after these changes...?? serialized response...??

Comment: There are no any migrations to apply.Ok there might be an issue on heroku on media files, but why isnt it coming on local server is my main confusion.

Comment: try to remove the migration and run it again... If you are getting the same API response then the mentioned changes are not reflected... these changes will make the response from `media/media/pictures` to `media/pictures`... and this response will match your file directory as you have mentioned.

Comment: No, Shivendra, the url has changed to media/pictures only after doing what you said, but still when I click on the image url, it sills shows 404 not found.